# Changing the color palette of an HTML page by a checkbox

Tags: html, color-palette

(**Update 2**: This question is in the context of an [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), although that's marginally relevant to the question.)

My users are split between sky lovers and forest lovers. Since I have no intention of telling them which color scheme to use, and since I likewise have no intention of releasing separate applications, I provide a checkbox that selects between the two palettes.

This is fairly straight-forward. We can for example select the containers and set their class.

```js
function change_palette(cb) {
    var bg = document.getElementById("somecontainer");
    var fg = document.getElementById("sometext");
    if(!cb.checked) {
        bg.className = "mycontainer sky_bgcol";
        fg.className = "mytext sky_fgcol";
    }
    else {
        bg.className = "mycontainer forest_bgcol";
        fg.className = "mytext forest_fgcol";
    }
}
```

```css
.sky_fgcol { color: #D6EAF8; }
.sky_bgcol { background-color: #2e86c1; }

.forest_fgcol { color: #D4EFDF; }
.forest_bgcol { background-color: #196F3D; }

.mycontainer { width: 400px; height: 300px; }
.mytext { text-align: center; }
.floatright { float: right; }
```

```html
<div id="somecontainer" class="mycontainer sky_bgcol">
    <div id="sometext" class="mytext sky_fgcol">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <label class="floatright">
            <input type='checkbox'
                onclick='change_palette(this);'>Sky/Forest
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

But there are two problems with this approach if instead of two colors we have six or seven, and instead of two DIVs we have a few dozen.

1. The `change_palette()` function is brittle. It needs to know which elements belong to which palette. Sooner or later someone will add an element and fail to revise this function appropriately.
2. The parts of each color scheme are not connected. The right solution would change one *pointer* to sky/forest to adjust the palette.

I can solve both problems by writing a configuration file that specifies, in just one place, the necessary settings.

But I'm wondering if doing that will be overkill and either SASS/SCCC has a feature that will solve this problem more nicely. Do they? Can you otherwise provide a pointer to a way for a good solution?

**Update 1**

Paul [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53163680/9295807) using CSS variables and then (in JavaScript) switching between color palettes, but this is undesirable both because the colors would be duplicated between CSS and Javascript (which is a maintenance headache that also renders the CSS variable definitions superfluous).

P.S.: I provided a MWE so that we can have a concrete Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to change the colors you should use css variables(custom properties):

```
:root{
    --main-color: #D6EAF8;
    --main-bg-color: #2e86c1;
}

.sky_fgcol { color: var(--main-color) }
.sky_bgcol { background-color: var(--main-bg-color) }
```

Then you use something like this to switch them:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--main-color', 'yellow');
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--main-bg-color', 'red');
```

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

if you want to switch the entire palette in one call you can do so by scoping everything on the body or a high level element, for instance you have class="sky" on  tag and you want to change it just replace that class with the new one. css must then be scoped like so:

```
.sky .fgcol{...}
.sky .bgcol{...}
```

Or you can use variables and scoping of variables:

```
.sky{
    --main-color: #D6EAF8;
    --main-bg-color: #2e86c1;
}
.fgcol{color: var(--main-color)}
```

like so you don't have to explicitly scope the classes and rewrite them just have different scopes defining all variables and then switch them from the body. with one class replace.

Comment: The main issue is that the name CSS "variables" is somewhat charitable. These constructs are akin not to variables, but to what are called macros in the C language, an utterly repugnant construct that's useless for programming in the large.

Comment: Well that may be true but in CSS it actually helps making large switches like that easy. I think it is a speed optimization for the CSS engine to handle it like this instead of actual variables (which I myself would very much love too).